# How to remove label from group tag in Odoo 11 in views

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-view, odoo-11

I want to show only the photo without the label which show the word Image and the line as showing in the photo 
i use group tag to make the screen two sides and i want only the photo in the left side without the label of it which is appear by default in group 
Is there ant ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the attribute `nolabel="1"` to your image field element

```xml
<field name="field_name" nolabel="1" />
```